# Modify a file in SharePoint document library

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007

I need to modify a file (text file) in a SharePoint document library. Tried to open a stream using SPFile.OpenBinaryStream() and write the data. But it doesn't work out. Any help/ suggestion would be appreciated.

Comment: "It doesn't work out" isn't much help. Is there an error or does nothing happen at all?

Answer (score 1):

Have you used the SaveBinary method?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spfile.savebinary.aspx

and depending on the doc library settings you may need to do a SPFile.CheckIn to commit the changes.